# Why this code with React Router doesn't work?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to use the Router provided by react but something doesn't work and I don't know what... First I used the BrowserRouter and I had an url like: home/login. However the Redirect didn't work in the build but only in the development enviromnent.  After that I changed BrowserRouter to HashRouter and, even if the Redirect works in the build, I have an url like that:
home/login#/home/login. What is wrong?

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <HashRouter basename={pack.homepage}> 
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <UserProvider>
          <Router />
        </UserProvider>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    </HashRouter>
  );
};
```

In the Router component:

```
<Aux>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
    {isAuthenticated ? <Route path="/" strict component={Main}/> : null}
    <Redirect to="/login"/>
  </Switch>
</Aux>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved thank to removing the basename